# How to get desired data from a String efficiently in java?

Tags: java

I have a String Text . I want to get value of "signature" keyword in Text.

Here is my code with example:

```
public void parseMethod(){
String Text = "hmac username=\"dhannan\", algorithm=\"hmac-sha1\", headers=\"content\", signature=\"VwjwFaNSw3cLQbuqtwl2XPOmcis=\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("signature=\"(.+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(authorization);
int s = Text.indexOf("signature=");
String data="";
int index=s+11;
while(Text.charAt(index)!='"'){
     data+=Text.charAt(index);
     index+=1;
   }
System.out.println(data);
}
```

So this will give me output that I want :

```
VwjwFaNSw3cLQbuqtwl2XPOmcis=
```

I don't like this method. I want to do in simple like regex or something other way.

By using regex way

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("signature=\"(.+)\"");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Text);
if(matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

But it gives this output while I want only value for which I will have to extra work like above:

```
signature="VwjwFaNSw3cLQbuqtwl2XPOmcis="
```

Please suggest me an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Use `matcher.group(1)` instead of plain `group()`, See the example here https://regex101.com/r/p1H08d/1

Answer (score 1):

Like 11thdimension suggested, you should use `matcher.group(1)` to find the value itself:

```
String Text = "hmac username=\"dhannan\", algorithm=\"hmac-sha1\", headers=\"content\", signature=\"VwjwFaNSw3cLQbuqtwl2XPOmcis=\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("signature=\"(.+)\"");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Text);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}

>> VwjwFaNSw3cLQbuqtwl2XPOmcis=
```